# How to accept upload in multer only after approval from server?

Tags: node.js, electron, multer

I'm writing an application that accepts uploads from a client to server using electron, node and multer.
What I wanna do is only allow the upload after the server has accepted it. Maybe some kind of prompt. How would I go about it in JS?

Even though I mentioned multer, I imagine it's not gonna play a big part in this. Rn, my upload function goes through like this.

```
var upload = multer({ storage: storage, })

app.post('/uploadfile', upload.single('single'), (req, res, next) => {
    const file = req.file
    if (!file) {
      const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
      error.httpStatusCode = 400
      return next(error)
    }
      res.send(file)
})
```

When the request comes, instead of running "upload.single", I imagine I have to use something else that prompts for validation and then run the actual upload function. But I'm very clueless. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Keep the upload process separate from authentication. To authenticate the user and then allow the same to upload the file.